# extracting specific json array element comparing all the array elements

Tags: java, android, json

I have the json object in the following format.

```
[
    {
        "StudentID": 1,
        "StudentMarks": [
            {
                "StudentID": 1,
                "English": 1500000,
                "Maths": 15,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 10,
                "TestID": 1,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            },
            {
                "StudentID": 1,
                "English": 155,
                "Maths": 1578,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 10,
                "TestID": 2,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            },
            {
                "StudentID": 1,
                "English": 155,
                "Maths": 15,
                "Science": 150,
                "History": 10,
                "TestID": 3,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            },
            {
                "StudentID": 1,
                "English": 150,
                "Maths": 15,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 10,
                "TestID": 6,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            },
            {
                "StudentID": 1,
                "English": 155,
                "Maths": 1578,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 10,
                "TestID": 7,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "StudentID": 2,
        "StudentMarks": [
            {
                "StudentID": 2,
                "English": 155,
                "Maths": 151,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 1025,
                "TestID": 4,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            },
            {
                "StudentID": 2,
                "English": 1551,
                "Maths": 15,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 100,
                "TestID": 5,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            },
            {
                "StudentID": 2,
                "English": 1,
                "Maths": 1,
                "Science": 15,
                "History": 10,
                "TestID": 8,
                "Date": "2018-01-29T14:38:11.01"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In this i need to list the student id and also the latest test marks in an android custom listview,

To extract each student id, i am using

```
JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject c= (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
    History= c.getString("History");
    Science= c.getString("Science");
    Maths= c.getString("Maths");
    English= c.getString("English");
}
```

But I want the student id and marks details of the latest test. which i thought of getting array element from 'StudentMarks' for which 'TestId' is maximum. How to do that?

Comment: Store your data in sqlite db and query to obtain your result

Comment: Please visit following question It was same like you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982412/how-to-search-find-in-json-with-java

Comment: what is `obj` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are able to iterate through and you are using below line of code to get all `StudentMarks`

```
JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
    History= obj.getString("History");
    ...
}
```

Then, IMO, you could store value when you get maximum `TestId` and to get the maximum `TestId`, you could initialize it with minimum value and whenever you get greater value overwrite all values to the latest one.

```
JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(jsonStr);
int test_id = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
    int curTestId = obj.getInt("TestID");
    if (test_id < curTestId)
    {
       History= obj.getString("History");
       Science= obj.getString("Science");
       Maths= obj.getString("Maths");
       English= obj.getString("English");
       test_id = curTestId;
    }
}

System.out.print("Maximum Test Id for this student :" + test_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue using the following code. Thanks @Ravi from whose answer i derived help.

```
JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(jsonStr);
int test_id = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
    id = obj.getString("StudentID");
    JSONArray sm = obj.optJSONArray("StudentMarks");
    for (int j=0; j<sm.length(); j++) 
    {
        JSONObject marksobj= (JSONObject) sm.get(j);
        int curTestId = marksobj.getInt("TestID");
        if (test_id < curTestId) {
            English= marksobj.getString("English");
            Science= marksobj.getString("Science");
            Maths= marksobj.getString("Maths");
            History= marksobj.getString("History");
            test_id = curTestId;
        }
    }
    HashMap<String, String> student= new HashMap<>();
    student.put("id", id);
    student.put("English", English);
    student.put("Science", Science);
    student.put("Maths", Maths);
    student.put("History", History);
    studentslist.add(student);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to access studentId and test result

```
try {
    JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject c= (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
        int studentId = c.optInt("StudentID", -1);

        int history, science, maths, english;
        JSONArray sm = c.optJSONArray("StudentMarks");
        for (int j=0; j<sm.length(); j++) {
            history= obj.getString("History");
            science= obj.getString("Science");
            maths= obj.getString("Maths");
            english= obj.getString("English");
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: How will this give StudentMarks with max TestID?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to find the studentId or Mark but to find the latest you should compare the testId every time and check the latest test mark.

To find studentId use @Aman Kumar Aggarwal code and to find latest marks below code will help

```
int previousId=0,currentId=0;
JSONObject latestMarks;

for{
.....
currentId = obj.getString("TestID");
if(currentId > previousId){
     previousId = currentID;
latestMarks = (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
}
}
```

the Object latestMarks  will be your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the manual parsing I would suggest to use the **Gson** library which will map your **Json** response to Pojo and then you can sort **StudentMarksDetail** using the **TestID** after that you do not have to iterate the entire list of find out then latest test. You can easily pickup the last element of the sorted list.
For Example:

```
data class StudentDetail(val list: MutableList<StudentMarkDetail>? = null, val studentId: Int? = null)

data class StudentMarkDetail(
        val studentID: String,
        val english: Int,
        val maths: Int,
        val science: Int,
        val history: Int,
        val testID: Int,
        val date: String
)

val studentDetail = StudentDetail()
studentDetail?.list?.sortBy { it.testID }
```

Now your StudentMarkDetail is sorted based on **TestID**. Now you can easily pickup the latest TestID from the last position for the list

And the usage of Gson:

```
val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
val gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(
NullStringToEmptyAdapterFactory()).create()
```

After creating the Gson reference you can use this internal method of Gson class to map the Json to Pojo

```
public <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
    Object object = fromJson(json, (Type) classOfT);
    return Primitives.wrap(classOfT).cast(object);
  }
```