# Invoking Rest API using java client passing json object

Tags: java, json, rest, api

I am new to JSON. I am invoking a public rest API
https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/cases

I want to query all the cases for a particular disease type( for example TCGA-LAML mentioned below).

in SOAP Ui when I POST below request in JSON format .It gives me perfect answer
    {
                     "filters":
                     {"op":"in",
                     "content":{
                   "field":"cases.project.project_id",
                    "value":["TCGA-LAML"]
                    }
                    }
                    }

But I have to call POST through a java client. Even after Trying hard I am not able to set the input parameters correctly.

I am posting my code here. Can you please help me correcting the code.

```
package downloadtoolproject; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Newtest {
    public static String sendPostRequest(String requestUrl, String payload) {
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(payload);
            writer.close();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                jsonString.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonString.toString() ;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String payload = "{\"field\":\"project_id\",\"value\":[\"TCGA-LAML\"]}";
        String requestUrl="https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/cases";
        sendPostRequest(requestUrl, payload);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to run this query :->  { "filters": {"op":"in", "content":{ "field":"cases.project.project_id", "value":["TCGA-LAML"] } } } ?

Comment: Yes Bhavya I want to run this query. But not able to make parameters of this.

Comment: Change "String payload" to -> String payload="{ \"filters\": {\"op\":\"in\", \"content\":{ \"field\":\"cases.project.project_id\", \"value\":[\"TCGA-LAML\"] } } }"; and now run your program and then tell me if you got your desired output, if yes then I will help you parameterise it!

Comment: Yes Bhavya this time it is giving desired results.

Comment: Great, Now which parameter do you want to be parameterised?

Comment: I want the value part to be parameterized. Instead of TCGA-LAML,I want to pass it as parameter. Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: Ok now since this is an array, can this parameter have multiple value at once for a single query?

Comment: yes Bhavya,It can have multiple values for a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following solution should work for you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Newtest {
    public static String sendPostRequest(String requestUrl, String payload) {
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(payload);
            writer.close();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonString.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("TCGA-LAML");
        String requestUrl = "https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/cases";
        sendPostRequest(requestUrl, preparePayload(values));

    }

    private static String preparePayload(List<String> values) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : values) {
            sb.append("\"" + value + "\",");
        }
        String desiredValue = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1);
        return "{ \"filters\": {\"op\":\"in\", \"content\":{ \"field\":\"cases.project.project_id\", \"value\":[" + desiredValue + "] } } }";
    }

}
```

You just need to add all the input values in the `values` List and pass it to the `preparePayload` method ,it will convert it into a valid payload.

Comment: Its good to hear that. Please accept the answer and close this question. Thanks

Comment: Hi Bhavya. Really sorry for again troubling you. {
   "data":    {
      "hits":       [
                 
                    
                  {
            "updated_datetime": "2018-05-24T11:22:57.727521-05:00",
           
            
            "submitter_id": "TCGA-AB-2956",
            
            "id": "c1f908ce-f6d5-4",
            
            "disease_type": "Acute Myeloid Leukemia",
            
            
         }
      ] portion of response. I want to access submitter_id,id and disease_type in my java code. can you please help with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982412/how-to-search-find-in-json-with-java this will help you with json parsing

Comment: Thanks Bhavya I tried this. But it has some issues json-path 2.4.0 doesn't have the correct API. While in 3.0.0 I get ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/internal/assertion/AssertParameter

Comment: Use the following pom entry to :-><dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency> . and remove the previous one, and I suggest you to start a new thread as answering your queries in comment section is difficult and not properly formatted