# How to fetch the JSON using GSON or simple-json API

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file with the below details.

```
{
"item":[
{
"id":"MPS1",
"shortname":"fres",
"field1":"76,728.76",
"field2":"370.50",
"field3":"-1.40",
"field4":"-0.38",
"field5":"-1",
"details":null,
"test1":"589.73l",
"url":"http://www.google.com"
},
{
"id":"MPS2",
"shortname":"fres1",
"field1":"76,7281.761",
"field2":"3701.50",
"field3":"-1.140",
"field4":"-10.38",
"field5":"-11",
"details":1,
"test1":"589.73l",
"url":"http://www.google.com"
},
```

Like this I have 50 structures in a single file and I need to validate and fetch the data based on the user input.

For example: if the user enters MPS2 as input, 
the code should search in the entire JSON file and display the structure which contains this pattern.

So the user should get the output as below

id:MPS2
shortname:fres1
field1:76,7281.761
field2:3701.50
field3:-1.140
field4:-10.38
field5:-11
details:1
test1:589.73l
url:http://www.google.com"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search/find In JSON with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982412/how-to-search-find-in-json-with-java)

Comment: are field names changing?  structure of each document is same. I mean all item contains shortName,field1 etc

Comment: Field Names are constant. only the values will be changing

Comment: user can search by any field or just by id field.