# What is the best way to extract a value without having a Java Object class

Tags: java, arrays, json, objectmapper

I have a string like below

```
{
    "id": "abc",
    "title": "123.png",
    "description": "fruits",
    "information": [
        {
            "type": "apple",
            "url": "https://apple.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "orange",
            "url": "https://orange.com"
        }
    ],
    "versions": 0
}
```

I want to get the value of `url` where `type: orange`. The list in `information` may not always be in same order as appearing in the data above. I know I could do it easily in python with `json.loads` and `json.dump`.

I am trying to do it java using `JsonNode` and `objectMapper.readTree.at("/information")` but I am unable to get past this point in a clever neat way to get the list and fetch the url where type = orange.

Comment: Does this help? [How to search/find In JSON with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982412/how-to-search-find-in-json-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward

Use a [JSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library and parse the response using the library. Then get only the values and attributes that you need...

Example relevant to your case:

```java
// Get your Json and transform it into a JSONObject

JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString); // Here is your JSON...

// Get your "information" array

JSONArray infoArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("information"); // Here you have the array

// Now you can go through each item of the array till you find the one you need

for(int i = 0 ; i < infoArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject item = participantsArray.getJSONObject(i);

    final String type = item.getString("type");
    final String url = item.getString("url");

    if(type.equals("orange"))
    {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED
    }
}
```